# Recursive class definitions in Python

Tags: python, class, recursion, fluent-interface, python-2.x

I am experimenting with fluent interfaces in Python.

An example of a fluent sql query generator would look something like this in usage:

```
sql.select('foo').select('bar').from('sometable').tostring()
```

I quickly realized that the ability to define nested classes recursively would probably help.

```
class sql:
    class select:        
        class select   # <--  HERE
        def __init__(self, dbcolumn, astype=None, asname=None):
            self.dbcolumn = dbcolumn
            self.astype = astype
            self.asname = asname
```

In the line marked with the comment '# <--  HERE':
I want this nested class reference to refer to the same 'select' class definition of the containing class.

Is this possible somehow? Maybe using some keyword that I am not aware of?

Comment: But `select` is a *method* on `sql`; it could return a class, but it is not itself a class..

Comment: That's... not how you implement a fluent interface.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that fluent interfaces are just not the way things are done in Python?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Nope, you just don't nest class definitions to implement fluent interfaces.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: select is *not* a method, just a nested class. Calling sql.select('foo') obviously calls the constructor of the sql.select class, returning an instance of the nested select class.

Comment: @Ries: but that would leave you no context of the parent class. There is no point in nesting classes that way, other than to confuse users of your API. It *should* be a method; your `sql.select` example told me you expected it to work like a method would.

Comment: Its still a work in progress. Here is a gist showing how to pass the context along: https://gist.github.com/3175416

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know that you wouldn't do it *that* way, but I mean that as a whole, designing fluent interfaces without good reason is something that would not be considered Pythonic. It's not typical to get jQuery-style chaining, for example.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: As SQLAlchemy shows, there are fine use-cases for chaining outside of jQuery, implementable in Python. I wouldn't say that this is thus un-pythonic.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for "recursive class definitions". All you need to do to allow chaining is to return `self` in your methods (or a instance of the same class if your objects are not mutable or some methods shouldn't modify the input object).

Example:

```
>>> class SQL(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.columns = []
...     def select(self, col):
...         self.columns.append(col)
...         return self
...
>>> s = SQL()
>>> s.select('foo').select('bar').columns
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: My (misplaced?) concern with this example is that adding a SQL.insert function would make something like this possible:
s.select('foo').insert()
which doesnt make sense in a SQL fluent interface.

Comment: Simply set a flag when `select` is called and raise an exception when `insert` is called on an object with the `select` flag set.

Comment: That sounds like an unnecessary hack.

Comment: If python had better code-completion compatibility the suggested flag would also not have played nice. But that is just a theoretical drawback.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing *classes* with *methods*.

`select` is a method on an instance of `class sql`, not a nested class. It could return another instance.

```
class SelectStatement(object):
    def select(self, tablename):
        return SelectStatement()

class SQL(object):
    def select(self, tablename):
        return SelectStatement()
```

Take a look at the source code of [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/); it does exactly that; generate SQL from a structure python classes, where you can refine a query by calling methods on instances in just such a manner. A series of joins for example, can be chained:

```
q = session.query(User).join(User.orders).join(Order.items).join(Item.keywords)
```

Comment: No confusion here. Maybe my use of lower case class names confused you? :)

Comment: @Ries: nope, I am pretty certain I was not confused there.

Comment: Thanks for the link to SQLAlchemy anyway.

Comment: @Ries: You want to return class instances based on the context of another instance. You do that via methods; if you just instantiated a nested class it would not inherit that context.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/3175416 for a way how I could pass the context along. But I concur, it uses a method that instantiates the same class. But I still like the nested class structure.

Comment: @Ries: Why use the parent `sql` class at all then? Why not just use a module instead? There is no practical reason for you to use the `sql` class there.

Answer (score 0):

As the title of the question indicated, I really wanted to know how to recursively nest a class definition. I am sure there are many ways to 'skin the fluent-interface-in-python cat'.

I found a way to recursively nest a class definition using decorators:

```
# class decorator
def recursiveclass(decorated_class):
    decorated_class.__dict__[decorated_class.__name__] = decorated_class
    return decorated_class     

#fluent interface
class sql:
    @recursiveclass
    class select:        
        def __init__(self, dbcolumn, astype=None, asname=None):
            self.dbcolumn = dbcolumn
            self.astype = astype
            self.asname = asname
```

Please note that I am not saying this is the best way to implement a fluent interface in Python. I am merely experimenting.

To verify:

```
dir(sql.select.select.select.select)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'select']
```

Comment: The example above does show how to recursively nest classes, but I am beginning to doubt the usefulness of doing this, as the child class has no access to its parent's attributes. Maybe this makes more sense for defining fluent interfaces: https://gist.github.com/3175416